# Var(X+X) = Var(X) + Var(X) or $2^2$ Var(X)?

Tags: probability, random-variables

"We want to measure the perimeter of rectangle ABCD. The measurement AB and CD have standard deviation of 3cm, whereas the measurement of BC and AD have St. deviation of 2cm.

b) What is the standard deviation for the perimeter if we measure each side and add them up? "

Answer: $\sqrt{26}$

Here is what I did so far:

Let X: Random variable of AB = CD measurement
    Y: RV of AD = BC measurement

$Var(X + X + Y + Y) = Var(2X + 2Y) = 2^2Var(X+Y) = 2^2Var(X) + 2^2 Var(Y) = 52 $

or

$Var(X + X + Y + Y) = Var(X) + Var(X) + Var(Y) + Var(Y) = 26$

Then of course, the standard deviation would be the square root of the variances.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it true to say that $Var(X+X) \mathrel{{=}\llap{/\,}} Var(X) + Var(X)$ because X is not independent of X? (I learnt that $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y)$ if X independent of Y) ?

   If yes, then the second calculation is wrong.
2. So the only way I see is if I assign each side of the rectangle a different random variable, but why should I? If two sides are the same, why can't I use the same random variable?

Comment: Answering your title question: $$V(X+X)=V(2X)=2^2V(X)=4V(X)\neq 2V(X)=V(X)+V(X).$$ Unless of course $V(X)=0$.

Comment: To answer your first question: Yes, it's because $X$ and $X$ are not independent. What is $V(X + Y)$ in general? $$E[(X + Y)^2] = E[X^2 + 2XY + Y^2] = E[X^2 + 2E[XY] + E[Y^2]$$ $$[E(X + Y)]^2 = [E(X) + E(Y)]^2 = E(X)^2 + 2E(X)E(Y) + E(Y^2)$$ Subtracting the above two: $$V(X + Y) = [E(X^2) - E(X)^2] + 2[E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) + [E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2].$$ Now denote $E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$ by $\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)$. Then $$V(X + Y) = V(X) + 2\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) + V(Y).$$

Comment: So in particular, $V(X + X) = V(X) + 2\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y) + V(X) = V(X) + 2V(X) + V(X) = 4V(X)$, which is consistent with the $V(2X) = 2^2 V(X)$.

Comment: If $\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y) = 0$, $X$ and $Y$ are said to be "uncorrelated". Then $V(X + Y) = V(X) + V(Y)$. A special case of this is when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, for then, $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y) \implies \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = 0$. Of course the converse is not true.

Comment: $\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)$ is the "covariance" of $X$ and $Y$ [It's defined as $E[(X - E(X))(Y - E(Y))]$, but that readily simplifies to the other formula]. Why are they "uncorrelated" when their _covariance_ is zero? Because if you normalise the covariance by dividing by the product of the standard deviations $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$, you get the __correlation__ between $X$ and $Y$ [Observe that $\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)$ is scale-dependent: $\mathrm{Cov}(aX, Y) = a\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)$, which doesn't make sense since scaling $X$ should not affect its degree of dependence with $Y$. Hence we normalise it].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to "question 1" at the end of your post is correct.

The answer to the original problem might be different than your approach, due to an interpretation of the question.
The problem says to "measure each side and add them up." This means you should measure AB and CD individually (possibly getting two different measurements even though they are the same length) and same for the other pair of sides. Then all four measurements are independent, and you may add up the four variances individually.

What you have done is measured one side (say, AB) once and assumed the opposite side (say, CD) has has the same length, and the same for the other pair of sides. If this is allowed, then your first computation (with answer $\sqrt{52}$) is correct. But this is not what the question is asking.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

The bilinearity of covariance states: $$\mathsf {Var}(X+Y)=\mathsf {Var}(X)+\mathsf {Var}(Y)+2\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)$$

Now, when $X,Y$ are independent, then their covariance is $0$, so $$\mathsf {Var}(X+Y)=\mathsf {Var}(X)+\mathsf {Var}(Y)$$

Similarly the bilineatity of covariance states.

$$\mathsf {Var}(X+X)=\mathsf {Var}(X)+\mathsf {Var}(X)+2\mathsf {Cov}(X,X)$$

Now, $X$ is *not* independent from $X$. Indeed, the covariance of $X$ and itself is the variance of $X$, so we have the following

$$\begin{split}\mathsf {Var}(X+X)&=\mathsf {Var}(X)+\mathsf {Var}(X)+2~\mathsf {Var}(X)\\&=4~\mathsf {Var}(X)\end{split}$$

And in general $\mathsf {Var}(aX)=a^2\mathsf {Var}(X)$ for any constant $a$, as derived from the definition for variance $\mathsf {Var}(aX)=\mathsf E(a^2X^2)-[\mathsf E(aX)]^2$ and the linearity of expectation.

---

> So the only way I see is if I assign each side of the rectangle a different random variable, but why should I? If two sides are the same, why can't I use the same random variable?

The *opposing* sides of a rectangle have equal lengths, the adjacent sides need not be.   $\lozenge\rm ABCD$ was specified as a rectangle, rather than a *square*.

So let the measurement of $\overline{\rm AB}$ and $\overline{\rm CD}$ be random variable $X$, and the measurement of $\overline{\rm AD}$ and  $\overline{\rm BC}$ be random variable $Y$.

$$\mathsf {Var}(2X+2Y)=4~(\mathsf{Var}(X)+\mathsf{Var}(Y))$$